# Replace part of link

Tags: javascript, regex, object, replace

I have the following link:

```
http://example.com/item/[{catalogueId:[0-9]}/key/[{translationId:[a-z]}]]/
```

In an Object I have the values I need to put in this link:

```
args: {catalogueId: 12, translationId: "en"}
```

Now I want the link to look this:

```
http://example.com/item/12/key/en/
```

But when the Object looks like this:

```
args: {catalogueId: 12}
```

The link needs to look like this:

```
http://example.com/item/12/key/
```

And if the Object is empty the `12` and the `key` should be left out of the link too.

The brackets decide what will be shown in the link. Everyting inside the brackets of `catalogueId` will only be shown when `catalogueId` is present in the Object.

I've already accomplished to replace the parameters between the curly brackets by this function:

```
for(var key in this.args) {
    var regex = new RegExp('{' + key + '\\b[^}]*}', 'g');
    this.pattern = this.pattern.replace(regex, this.args[key]);
}
```

But I have no clue how to do the part of the brackets

Comment: @epascarello I added what I already have, but I have no idea how I can do the part of the brackets.

Comment: Why do you have to replace from a string, if you know the pattern, can't you just build it?

Comment: @epascarello because the link is a variable too. Nothing is hardcoded.

Comment: When you say "But when the object looks like this" don't you mean "But when the link looks like this"? As epascarello says, if you have the object as a given, creating the link is trivial. It sounds like you are uncertain ahead of time what the *link* will be, and are not sure how to make the object like in your first example. Am I wrong?

Comment: `http://example.com/item/[{catalogueId:[0-9]}/key/[{translationId:[a-z]}]]/` makes this *really* awkward to do. Are you sure you don't have `http://example.com/item/[{catalogueId:[0-9]}]/key/[{translationId:[a-z]}]/` (note where the closing `]` for `catalogueId` is).

Comment: @Katana314 the content of the Object can change. So yes, I'm certain it's ight what I've said. the content of the object is just what I wrote in my input fields.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes I know it's very awkward, but this is how the [slim framework](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#optional-segments) works.

Comment: @InbarAzulay: Then a single regex in JavaScript can't do it, they don't have nesting constructs like some regex engines do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I was thinking that too sadly. But I have no idea to accomplish this. Do you maybe know another way to do this?

Comment: why not use regex to remove the array brackets before doing the replacement of the properties

Comment: @synthet1c that is possible but then the depth in the brackets fall away. The variables could go as deep as 100 layers.

Comment: I can't think of anything apart from creating a parser for the array brackets by counting and matching the open and closed brackets, then recursively working inward

Comment: @synthet1c I will try that, thanks! If I make it work I will post my code on here

Comment: @InbarAzulay cool I would be interested to see it.

Comment: @InbarAzulay answer updated

Answer (score 1):

As per your newest requirements I have updated the solution. It ain't pretty but it works, I think this may be overkill when you could just remove the array brackets and cut the string where it's unable to do the replacement.

Checkout the comments for an explanation.

```js
const url = 'http://example.com/item/[{catalogueId:[0-9]}/key/[{translationId:[a-z]}]]/'

const REGEX = {
  type: /\[([0-9-a-z]+)\]/g,      // [type]
  brackets: /\[|\]/,              // [|]
  keyType: /\{(\w+)\:([^\}]+)\}/, // {key:[type]}
  placeholder: /\{[^\}]+\}/g      // the entire {placeholder}
}

function test(url, params) {
  // split the url into it's compontent parts
  const parts = url.replace(REGEX.type, '($1)')
    .split(REGEX.brackets)
    .filter(str => str !== '')
  
  const ret = []
  
  for (let ii = 0; ii < parts.length; ii++) {
    // find the key and type
    const matches = parts[ii].match(REGEX.keyType)
    if (matches == null) {
      // no placeholders in this section, just add it to the return
      ret[ii] = parts[ii]
    }
    else {
      const [match, key, type] = matches
      if (typeof params[key] !== 'undefined') {
        // replace the placeholder with the provided value
        ret[ii] = parts[ii].replace(REGEX.placeholder, () => {
          // you could do param type checking here
          return params[key]
        })
      }
      else {
        // this iterations placeholder doesn't match, time to quit
        break
      }
    }
  }
  // if we get through the loop return the url
  return ret.join('')
}

const tests = [
  // it should accept no params
  test(url, {}),
  // it should not include placeholders that are missing
  test(url, {
    catalogueId: 10
  }),
  // it should fill in all placeholders
  test(url, {
    catalogueId: 10,
    translationId: 'test'
  }),
  // it should not skip placeholders
  test(url, {
    translationId: 'test'
  }),
  // it should not error with invalid params
  test(url, {
    invalid: 'param'
  })
]

tests.map(result => console.log(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

I had to get rid of the array brackets as it was too hard to get regex to work with them without a bunch of code. but this will do the same thing by removing any placeholders that aren't matched.

```js
const test1 = {
  catalogueId: 12, 
  translationId: "en"
}

const test2 = {catalogueId: 12}

const url = 'http://example.com/item/{catalogueId:[0-9]}/key/{translationId:[a-z]}/'

const reg = /\{([^:]+):(\[[^\]]+\])\}/g

const replace = url => components => {
  // replace all the placeholders in the url
  const replaced = url.replace(reg, (_, key, type) => {
    return components[key]
  })
  // clean off any missing values
  const cutIndex = replaced.indexOf('undefined')
  
  return cutIndex < 0
    ? replaced 
    : replaced.substr(0, cutIndex)
}

console.log(
  replace(url)(test1) // 'http://example.com/item/12/key/en/'
)
console.log(
  replace(url)(test2) // 'http://example.com/item/12/key/'
)
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Comment: The OP's confirmed in a comment that their format string is correctly quoted in the question and they can't change it.